# JAVA Adding line breaks to a string after a certain combination of characters?

Tags: java, regex

I am pretty new to Java (started a course less than half a year ago) and I'm not sure how to go about implementing this. Hopefully it can be covered with some sort of regex - though I haven't covered regex in my course yet so if someone can explain their answer briefly it would be appreciated.

Here is the code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
public class definerNotOrganised

{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("\f\n\tWelcome to the word definer! (Input '*' to exit)");
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("\n\tEnter a word to Define: ");
            input();
        }
    }

private static  void input() throws Exception 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
    String userWord = sc.nextLine();
    if (userWord.equalsIgnoreCase("*"))
    {
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(define(userWord));
    }

}

private static String define(String word) throws Exception
{                
    String notFound = "I'm sorry, I can't find that word...";
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sujithps/Dictionary/master/Oxford%20English%20Dictionary.txt").openStream()));     
    try {
        while (line != null)
        {                             
            line = br.readLine();      
            String lineFirstWord = firstWord(line);
            if ((lineFirstWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word))&&(line.length() > 5))
            {
                cleanUp(line);       
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception E) 
    {
        return notFound;
    }
    return notFound;
}     

private static String firstWord(String line) {
    if (line.indexOf(' ') > -1)
    { 
        return line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')); 
    } else 
    {
        return line; 
    }
}

private static void cleanUp(String line) 
{
//Unsure what to put in here
}

}
```

The code I am writing is meant to define words, which it does by searching https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sujithps/Dictionary/master/Oxford%20English%20Dictionary.txt for a definition of a word the user enters. It isn't very optimal and takes a while to search - but that's not what I'm trying to solve right now.

I'm sure there are many issues but currently what I want to know is what to put in the `cleanUp` method to make the output better.

The main issue with my code is that the output can be very messy if the word has multiple definitions.

For example, the output for the word "nice" would be:

> Nice  adj. 1 pleasant, satisfactory. 2 (of a person) kind, good-natured. 3 iron. Bad or awkward (nice mess). 4 fine or subtle (nice distinction). 5 fastidious; delicately sensitive. 6 (foll. By an adj., often with and) satisfactory in terms of the quality described (a nice long time; nice and warm).  nicely adv. Niceness n. Nicish adj. (also niceish). [originally = foolish, from latin nescius ignorant]

This gets printed out all in one line by the console, which looks messy. I want the output to be something more like this:

> Nice  adj.
>
> 1. pleasant, satisfactory.
> 2. (of a person) kind, good-natured.
> 3. iron. Bad or awkward (nice mess).

etc.

Originally I thought that the solution was to have the code find a number in the string, and then add a `\n` before it.

However, some of the definitions themselves contain numbers so this wouldn't work out.

Each time there is a new definition it comes after the end of a sentence, so ideally the code needs to look for `. [a number]` and then line break before the number.

It also needs to accommodate for up to two digit numbers, because some words have a lot of definitions.

As further safe-proofing (just incase the conditions are met somewhere unexpected) it would be useful if it only applied the line break when the number is one higher that the last one it did. (if the code finds ". 1" and then for some reason ". 7" it should not line break, but if it finds ". 2" it should.)

Sorry if something similar to this has been posted before, but I'm not even sure where to start with this. Someone I know who is much more competent than I tried to offer a regex solution but it didn't work out, hopefully someone here can be of assistance.

Not all the criteria from before needs to be met really, it doesn't have to be perfect, I just wanted to give an idea of what I am going for. Sorry for the long read and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is too broad and not very clear. Could you cut your program in smaller parts, try to code each one, and reformulate your problem more precisely ?

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina and to the OP too: the code is completely irrelevant and should even be removed. The most important thing to do in regex questions is to give clear rules and ample input and expected output results. The OP's attempt should also be posted, though here they did mention what they tried and why it didn't work, and their attempt is simple enough to not show the code (in my opinion).

Comment: "*Each time there is a new definition it comes after the end of a sentence, so ideally the code needs to look for `. [a number]` and then line break before the number.*" Looks good, did you try to write it? What didn't work? What about multiple grammatical functions of a word (both noun and verb)?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a harder time than you think because of the dictionary format. Printed (As opposed to online) dictionaries use many formatting techniques to shorten the length of the text and thus of the book itself.

Operating on the basis that you need to look for a period followed by a number (`. #`) will not be enough. Look in your example what you will get for definition 6:

> 6. (foll. By an adj., often with and) satisfactory in terms of the quality described (a nice long time; nice and warm). nicely adv. Niceness n. Nicish adj. (also niceish). [originally = foolish, from latin nescius ignorant]

But this is incorrect because the dictionary format is such that different [parts of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) are written sequentially. What you would *probably* like is to have

> Nice adj.
>
> ...
>
> 6. (foll. By an adj., often with and) satisfactory in terms of the quality described (a nice long time; nice and warm).
>
> nicely adv.
>
> Niceness n.
>
> Nicish adj. (also niceish). [originally = foolish, from latin nescius ignorant]

And this is excluding any other formatting conventions. You will have to consult the first pages in the dictionary that explain all the abbreviations and definition format.

For now, I suggest you write a list of keyword, like `adj`, `adv`, `n` etc. and search for them *in addition* to searching for `. #`. Here is an incomplete attempt:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String[] KEYWORDS = {" adj\\. ", " n\\. ", " adv\\. "};

    String s = "Nice adj. 1 pleasant, satisfactory. 2 (of a person) kind, good-natured. 3 iron. Bad or awkward (nice mess). 4 fine or subtle (nice distinction). 5 fastidious; delicately sensitive. 6 (foll. By an adj., often with and) satisfactory in terms of the quality described (a nice long time; nice and warm). nicely adv. Niceness n. Nicish adj. (also niceish). [originally = foolish, from latin nescius ignorant]";
    String r = s;

    for (String kw : KEYWORDS)
        r = r.replaceAll(kw + "(?![^(]+\\))", kw + "\n");
    r = r.replaceAll("\\.\\s+(\\d+)", ".\n $1.");
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

with the output

> Nice adj.
>
> 1. pleasant, satisfactory.
> 2. (of a person) kind, good-natured.
> 3. iron. Bad or awkward (nice mess).
> 4. fine or subtle (nice distinction).
> 5. fastidious; delicately sensitive.
> 6. (foll. By an adj., often with and) satisfactory in terms of the quality described (a nice long time; nice and warm). nicely adv.
>
> Niceness n.
>
> Nicish adj.
>
> (also niceish). [originally = foolish, from latin nescius ignorant]

Note that one would need an arbitrary length lookbehing to fix the `nicely adv.` in definition 6. Also, in the `Nicish adj.` form the additional info should not be separated with a line break.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, much appreciated!

Comment: @Ramkh Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I myself am new to Java, but I thought I could give it a try. I added "fake" numbers in the enumeration to make sure it works correctly. I encourage more experienced Java programmers to comment on this post to further improve things.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Nice adj. 1 pleasant, satisfactory. 2 (of a person) kind,"
                + " good-natured. 3 iron. 2 A fake number. Bad or awkward (nice mess). 4 fine or"
                + " subtle (nice distinction). 5 fastidious; delicately "
                + "sensitive. 8 Another fake number. 6 (foll. By an adj., often with and) satisfactory"
                + " in terms of the quality described (a nice long time; nice"
                + " and warm). nicely adv. Niceness n. Nicish adj. (also "
                + "niceish). [originally = foolish, from latin nescius ignorant]";

        String strClean = cleanUp(str);

        System.out.println(strClean);
    }

    private static String cleanUp(String str) {
        StringBuilder cleaned = new StringBuilder();
        int currentLevel = 0;

        /* The initial pre-digit information */
        Matcher initialMatcher = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(?=\\. 1)").matcher(str);
        // We must initialise the matcher before grouping
        boolean initialMatchBool = initialMatcher.find();
        cleaned.append(initialMatcher.group(1) + ".");

        /* Digit listing */
        List<String> startDigitList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher startDigitMatcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\. )(\\d[^\\d]*)").matcher(str);

        while (startDigitMatcher.find()) {
            startDigitList.add(startDigitMatcher.group());
        }

        for (String match: startDigitList) {
            /* The first digit of a match */
            Matcher digitMatcher = Pattern.compile("(^\\d+)").matcher(match);
            // We must initialise the matcher before grouping
            boolean digitMatchBool = digitMatcher.find();
            int precedingDigit = Integer.parseInt(digitMatcher.group(1));

            if (precedingDigit == currentLevel+1) {
                cleaned.append("\n\t");
                currentLevel++;
            }
            cleaned.append(match);
        }

        return cleaned.toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Nice adj.
    1 pleasant, satisfactory. 
    2 (of a person) kind, good-natured. 
    3 iron. 2 A fake number. Bad or awkward (nice mess). 
    4 fine or subtle (nice distinction). 
    5 fastidious; delicately sensitive. 8 Another fake number. 
    6 (foll. By an adj., often with and) satisfactory in terms of the quality described (a nice long time; nice and warm). nicely adv. Niceness n. Nicish adj. (also niceish). [originally = foolish, from latin nescius ignorant]
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest that if you are new and are not sure if this answer is good, then don't post it. Something like "*Do you really need a Pattern, a Matcher and then also initialise the regular expression with .find()?*" can be a question by itself on this site. People who know even less read this later and it will only confuse them or teach them wrong things. With that being said, what you wrote is not terrible, but could certainly be improved. Also note that definition 6 contains more than just that.

Comment: @user1803551 Considering that this a Q&A website, driven by the community it only seems right for me to post this. I will leave out my questionable comment, but apart from that I stand behind it. I am trying to help the OP out, which others do not. I, then, provide an initial shot at the bird and I encourage others to provide comments. That way, three birds get hit with one stone: the OP gets his answer, I learn from it, and the ones helping out do not have to start lookng for a whole new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your concern that "fake" numbers might exist in the text is unfounded, and further you couldn't realistically guard against a "fake" number that happened to match the next expected sequential number.

Thus, this will suffice:

```
String formatted = definition.replaceAll("\\. (\\d+)", ".\n\t$1");
```

Comment: Not quite, look what you get for definition 6 (in the given example).